# std::print() and template parameter pack

Tags: c++, printing, variadic-templates, c++23, parameter-pack

Would be possible to print a template parameter pack using std::print?
something like:

```
void func(auto... args){
    std::print("???", args...);
}
```

EDIT: if it wasn't clear: "???" means that I don't know what to put there, what construct to use in order to print the args passed to func(). What func() does is completely irrelevant and independent of that std::print() call.

Someting like:
a call to func(a, b, c) to result in a call to std::print("{}{}{}", a, b, c)

SOLUTION: the closest one I could find (thanks @Passer By, I'll credit it to you if no better solution comes up in a few days):

```
auto func1(auto&&...args){/*...*/return 0;}//actual work on args
auto func0(auto&& arg, auto&&...args){
    //print args (no std::forward() here because we need the args later)
    std::print("{}", "args(");
    std::print("{}", arg);             //1st arg
    (std::print(", {}", args), ...);   //unfold the rest of the args
    std::println(")");
    //do something with the arguments
    return func1(std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg), std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
}
func0(1); //prints: args(1)
func0(2, "abc"); //prints: args(2, abc)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `func`? Why can't you pass the format string to it? Or, with the current [mre] you don't even need it. Please [edit] your question to give us more context and details.

Comment: What have you tried? It should work out of the box. What is the aim to wrap `std::print` with `func`?

Comment: @MarekR Well, `std::print("???", args...)` does literally work (and prints `???`) but I suspect OP wants to do something other than that. Unfortunately I don't actually know what something it is that they want to do.

Answer (score 4):

You use a fold expression

```
void func(auto... args)
{
    (std::print("{} ", args), ...);
}
```

To get rid of the trailing space

```
void func(auto arg, auto... args)
{
    std::print("{}", arg);
    (std::print(" {}", args), ...);
}
```

Also, you should be forwarding arguments

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void func(T&& arg, Ts&&... args)
{
    std::print("{}", std::forward<T>(arg));
    (std::print(" {}", std::forward<Ts>(args)), ...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Passer By, your solution works fine.
I was hoping for a solution that doesn't repeatedly call std::print() for each argument and to be solved, if possible, at compile time...

Comment: _"doesn't repeatedly call"_ why? And what about this code do you think is not "compile time"?

Comment: I prefer std::print() to be called only once if possible, for performance reasons.
I added an example of what (utopic) thing I would like

Comment: There are ways to build the format string, but it's more complicated and it isn't worth the effort unless you can demonstrate that calling `std::print` with a single argument is a performance issue.

Comment: No demonstration needed, It is a fact: one function call is cheaper that 10 function calls

Comment: @Solo No, it's not. Additionally, you're thinking about performance in exactly the wrong way. You always identify a performance issue first with profiling, then and *only then* do you optimize. Comments have gotten off-topic far enough, I'll stop here.